# Applying displacement control loading using Lagrange multipliers in the material non-linear finite element method

Tags: matrix, finite-element-analysis, nonlinear-equation, elasticity

Hi I am trying to implement a simple plasticity based finite element code. I am not clear how to set up displacement control applied through Lagrange multipliers. In case of a linear problem, I did the following to apply displcament control and it worked. If the energy balance was linear then the following equations would be obtained:
[image]

However, incase of non-linear problems, the K is  K(u) and is non-linear. So the energy balance equation and its derivative will be like as follows

[image]

It feels wrong. How do I evaluate this? How are the matrix form of equations modified in the non-linear case? So how do the matrix equations get modified? I used the https://codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php to add images typed in latex. Let me know if its not clear.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the way plasticity was modeled when I did FEA for a living.

Plasticity is modeled as a non-linear stress-strain material relationship, not with displacements and Lagrange multipliers.

Non-linear problems are typically expressed in terms of linearized increments:

```
K(u)*du = F(t)
u(t+dt) = u(t) + du
F(t+dt) = F(t) + dF
```

1. Start with an initial guess for displacement.
2. Apply a load increment.
3. Solve iteratively for the displacement increment until it converges.
4. Update the displacement and load vectors,
5. Go to step 2 and repeat.

Comment: I know this. Iam not interested in this. I want to use lagrange multipliers

Comment: Your physics aren’t correct.  Dislocation motion in metals is a material effect, not a boundary condition.

Comment: Hi my interst is to apply Lagrange multipliers for a non-linear problem. Applying Lagrange multipliers in a non-linear setup. I am not solving dislocations. What I mean by boundary condition is merely a displacement control loading. Is that clear?

Comment: Your physics are incorrect.  Loading is not material behavior.  Metal plasticity is dislocation motion.  Is that clear?   Perhaps the problem you really have in mind happens to be non-linear in some way but you're using the word "plasticity" in the wrong context.

Comment: Yes loading is not nonlinear. Neither loading is a material parameter. I am only trying to solve a non-linear problem. I am not bothered about how the non-linearity is induced. But plasticity could be one way I thought. As I said, I am only interested in arriving at equations for the Lagrange multiplier for any non-linear setup? Have I clarified?